# Spacy : ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found. (Error while loading Japanese Model)

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, anaconda, spacy

### How to reproduce the behaviour

On Anaconda Prompt, I created an environment : my_env
Here, I installed spacy (`pip install -U spacy`) and downloaded English and Japanese Model (`python -m spacy download ja_core_news_sm`). Loading english model gave no error.

But when I do :

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("ja_core_news_sm")
```

It gave the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nitin.trivedi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\spacy\lang\ja\__init__.py", line 31, in try_sudachi_import
    from sudachipy import dictionary, tokenizer
  File "C:\Users\nitin.trivedi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\sudachipy\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from . import utf8inputtextbuilder
  File "C:\Users\nitin.trivedi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\sudachipy\utf8inputtextbuilder.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .dictionarylib.categorytype import CategoryType
  File "C:\Users\nitin.trivedi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\anno\lib\site-packages\sudachipy\dictionarylib\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from . import doublearraylexicon
  File "C:\Users\nitin.trivedi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\sudachipy\dictionarylib\doublearraylexicon.py", line 17, in <module>
    from dartsclone import DoubleArray
  File "C:\Users\nitin.trivedi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\dartsclone\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from dartsclone._dartsclone import DoubleArray
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\nitin.trivedi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py", line 30, in load
    return util.load_model(name, **overrides)
  File "C:\Users\nitin.trivedi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py", line 170, in load_model
    return load_model_from_package(name, **overrides)
  File "C:\Users\nitin.trivedi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py", line 191, in load_model_from_package
    return cls.load(**overrides)
  File "C:\Users\nitin.trivedi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\ja_core_news_sm\__init__.py", line 12, in load
    return load_model_from_init_py(__file__, **overrides)
  File "C:\Users\nitin.trivedi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py", line 239, in load_model_from_init_py
    return load_model_from_path(data_path, meta, **overrides)
  File "C:\Users\nitin.trivedi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py", line 203, in load_model_from_path
    nlp = cls(meta=meta, **overrides)
  File "C:\Users\nitin.trivedi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\spacy\language.py", line 186, in __init__
    make_doc = factory(self, **meta.get("tokenizer", {}))
  File "C:\Users\nitin.trivedi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\spacy\lang\ja\__init__.py", line 273, in create_tokenizer
    return JapaneseTokenizer(cls, nlp, config)
  File "C:\Users\nitin.trivedi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\spacy\lang\ja\__init__.py", line 139, in __init__
    self.tokenizer = try_sudachi_import(self.split_mode)
  File "C:\Users\nitin.trivedi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\my_env\lib\site-packages\spacy\lang\ja\__init__.py", line 44, in try_sudachi_import
    "Japanese support requires SudachiPy and SudachiDict-core "
ImportError: Japanese support requires SudachiPy and SudachiDict-core (https://github.com/WorksApplications/SudachiPy). Install with `pip install sudachipy sudachidict_core` or install spaCy with `pip install spacy[ja]`.
```

I tried installing `pip install sudachipy sudachidict_core`
I checked for dartsclone and verified that it is already present.

### Environment

- Operating System: Windows 10
- Python Version Used: 3.6.10
- spaCy Version Used: 2.3.2
- Environment Information: Anaconda

Comment: Why use pip to install spacy?

Comment: as per instructions in the spacy documentation

Comment: It's also available as a Conda package, though.

Comment: This seems to be some weird bug/library issue that comes with installing spaCy via `conda`.  After many days of banging my head against the wall I managed to build Windows `conda` packages for `sudachipy` and its requirements.  Try `conda install -c dmnapolitano sudachipy` and also `dartsclone` and `sudachidict-core`.  They're working for me and I hope you have the same luck 